# How can I programmatically add data binding to a Web Performance Test?

Tags: c#, web-testing

Assume the following:

```
[DataSource("SomeDataSource", "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\SomeDataSource.xml", Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.DataBindingAccessMethod.Sequential, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.DataBindingSelectColumns.SelectOnlyBoundColumns, "SomeTable")]
[DataBinding("SomeDataSource", "SomeTable", "SomeColumn", "SomeContextParamter")]
public abstract WebTestBase: WebTest
{
     protected IList<WebTestRequest> _requests = new List<WebTestRequest>();

     public WebTestBase()
     {
         this.PreAuthenticate = true;
         this.Proxy = "default";
     }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
         // Error: Parameter doesn't exist in context.
         string parameter = this.Context["SomeContextParameter"].ToString();

         this.CreateRequests();

         // Some more code.
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<WebTestRequest> CreateRequests();
}

[CodedWebTest]
public DerivedWebTest: WebTestBase
{
     protected override IEnumerable<WebTestRequest> CreateRequests()
     {
          // Error: Parameter doesn't exist in context.
          string parameter = this.Context["SomeParameter"].ToString();

          // Some more code.
     }
}
```

This is properly loading from the data source to the Context property like it should when the DataBindingAttribute is applied.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?  Also, this doesn't seem like a complete code example.    See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It is complete in that much of the heavy lifting is done by the framework.  In the DerivedWebTest class, there is an indexer property called Context that gets populated with  the data provided in the attributes.  The error is that the Context property is NOT being populated with the data from the data source although I can verify that the property DataSources has loaded the data via the DataSourceAttribute.  The only thing not displayed it the GetEnumerator method that gets overridden in derived classes that derive from WebTest; I'll add it if that helps.

Comment: Added more code for more information.